# I am trying to install facebook php business sdk but i am getting below Fatal error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, facebook

I am trying to install facebook php business sdk but I am getting below Fatal error.

I used the below command
composer require facebook/php-business-sdk
But I am below fatal error
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 83
For reference please find the below image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Memory Limit issue,

Primarily you can use the following command

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require <package-name>
```

Permanently, you need to update the PHP memory limit.

Comment: but i am getting like this Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: i has increase the memory limit even though i am getting above error